# Select the latest node for each defined taxonomy term in Drupal 6

Tags: mysql, drupal, drupal-6

Can anyone help me out with a query to display 1 node for each taxonomy in Drupal 6?

For example, I have 4 taxonomy terms (tid = 21, 22, 23, 24) in a 1 vocabulary (vid = 3).

I would like to display a table showing:

Taxonomy Term:

1. Taxonomy
2. Description
3. Number of Nodes in Taxonomy Term
4. Title of latest node in taxonomy term
5. Last Commented/Updated Date

Thanks,
JK

Comment: Reading this http://drupal.org/node/748844 and http://sethsandler.com/code/drupal-6-creating-activity-stream-views-custom-sql-query-merging-multiple-views-part-1/ helped me to get an idea of where to start. I will post my results once I figured it out.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, just use http://drupal.org/project/views =) You don't need any hooks, etc.

and if you need to output this view in your custom module or whatever, you can do the following:
create view, then call it programmatically:

```
  $view = views_get_view('view_name');
  $view->set_arguments(array($order->products[0]->nid)); // pass arguments to view, if it is required
  return $view->render('Defaults'); //return rendered view
```

OR

```
$view->execute();
```

After this, you can access rows data without HTML output in $view->result variable.

Hope this helps.